Find and replace n-th occurrence in VS Code
I have a large data set that I'd like to convert into a workable csv file.
The dataset currently looks like this:
[att1]; [att2]; [att3]; [att1]; (...)

To make this a workable csv-file, I'd need to insert a line-break after every third semi-colon.
[att1]; [att2]; [att3];
[att1]; [att2]; [att3]; (...)

Using VS Code's find and replace feature, how can I achieve this?

I am open to using other methods/software. If you know any, please mention them in a comment.

See regex101 demo
If your data is all on one line with the formatting you showed - [.*?];  then
Find: ((\[.*?\]; ?){3})
Replace: $1\n
seems to do the job.  It finds 3 of those att's with an optional space between them and adds a newline after that group of three.
If your data doesn't actually have the []'s, like att1; att2; att3;  you can use this find:
Find: ((.*?; ?){3})
